# Inconsistent reading of string from pipe

Tags: c, pipe

I read some data from a file, and send it through a pipe. When I read the data from the pipe, sometimes there's extra characters inside. The extra characters are also inconsistent, but normally is an extra "R" at the end.

The data I read from the file is correct, as it is always as it should be. It's only after reading it from the pipe that I encounter problems.

Could you help me find the error? I've been staring at this for ages and I can't find it.

This is the part of my code that is giving me trouble.

Thanks for your help.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int nClients;
    int file_name_HTML[2];

    create_pipes(file_name_HTML, server_access_request);
    init_free_pipes();

    nClients = getHTMLFilesIntoPipe(file_name_HTML);
    int clients[nClients];

    for(int i=0; i < nClients; i++)
    { 
        if((clients[i] = fork()) == 0) 
        { 
            clientFunction(file_name_HTML, server_access_request);
        } 
    }
    .....
}

int getHTMLFilesIntoPipe(int *file_name_HTML)
{
    int i, n = 0;
    char (*lines)[MAXCHAR] = NULL;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("./data/listado_html.txt", "r");

    if (!fp) {  /* valdiate file open for reading */
    err_exit("error: file open failed.\n");
    }

    if (!(lines = malloc (MAXLINES * sizeof *lines))) {
    err_exit("error: virtual memory exhausted 'lines'.\n");
    }

    while (n < MAXLINES && fgets (lines[n], MAXCHAR, fp)) /* read each line */
    { 
        char *p = lines[n];                 /* assign pointer  */
        for (; *p && *p != '\n'; p++) {}    /* find 1st '\n'   */
        if (*p != '\n') /* check line read */
        {                   
            int c;  
            while ((c = fgetc (fp)) != '\n' && c != EOF) {} /* discard remainder of line with getchar  */
        }
        *p = 0, n++;    /* nul-termiante   */
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        write(file_name_HTML[WRITE], lines[i], strlen(lines[i]));
    }

    free(lines);

    return n;
}

void clientFunction(int *file_name_HTML, int *server_access_request)
{
    char fileName[MAXCHAR];

    close(file_name_HTML[WRITE]);
    //Read HTML file name
    read(file_name_HTML[READ], fileName, MAXCHAR - 1);
    printf("%s\n", fileName);

    .......
}
```

Expected output:
abcd1.html

abcd2.html

abcd3.html

abcd4.html

abcd5.html

Current output:
abcd1.htmlR

abcd2.htmlR

abcd3.htmlR

abcd4.htmlR

abcd5.htmlR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because your string is not null(`\0`) terminated.

As you write to the pipe excluding null(`\0`) terminator.

```
write(file_name_HTML[WRITE], lines[i], strlen(lines[i])+1);
                                                        ^--- +1 to include null character.
```

> `strlen` returns the length excluding null terminator.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that... Thanks.